# Identifing a formula for the contribution of IR scattering to the permittivity of metals

Tags: scattering, refraction, absorption, infrared-radiation

I'm using a software modelling the complex refractive index of different materials in the THz/far infrared frequency range. One of the parameters that the user can add to the model of the permittivity is scattering. I'm trying to figure out what kind of scattering and where the formula is coming from. The authors of the software told me that "it comes from a book, just trust us", but I'd like to have something citable.

The formula for the complex relative permittivity extracted from the source code is:

$$\epsilon_\mathrm{total}(\omega)  = \epsilon_\mathrm{Drude}  + n_\mathrm{diff}^2 + 2 n_\mathrm{diff} \sqrt{\epsilon_\mathrm{Drude}} $$

which is equivalent to the addition of the refractive indices:

$$ n_\mathrm{total}(\omega) = n_\mathrm{Drude}  + n_\mathrm{diff}$$

where $n_\mathrm{diff} = - i \beta \left( \omega / 2 \pi \right)^3$, $\beta$ is the scattering coefficient and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. Which means that in term of complex refractive index $n_\mathrm{diff} = n -i \kappa$, the imaginary part is $\kappa(f) = \beta f^3$. Or in term of the absorption coefficient $\alpha = 2 \omega \kappa /c$, I'm looking for $$\alpha(\omega) = \frac{2 \omega^4 \beta}{(2 \pi)^3 c}.$$

Among the different kind of optical scatterings I can find, I'm guessing I can exclude:

- Compton scattering which is for high-frequency photons.
- Rayleigh scattering which doesn't apply to metals.
- Mie scattering which is not for bulk samples.
- Rutherford/Coulomb/Mott scattering that are not about photons.

Possible candidates:

- Brillouin scattering
- Raman scattering
- Thomson scattering

Of those 3, Thomson scattering seems the most likely candidate, but I still struggle to find any formula about how it affects the refractive index/absorption coefficient/complex permittivity.

The most promising clue I found is in [Quantum theory of Thomson scattering](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.hedp.2014.08.002) (open access), where Eq. 91 describes "the bremsstrahlung reduced absorption coefficient":

$$\tilde{\kappa}_{\mathrm{br}}(\omega) = 2 \frac{\Omega_e^2 T}{\omega^3 c} (1-e^{-\omega/T}) \nu_{\mathrm{br}}(\omega)$$

which modifies the Drude model, but doesn't shows a dependency in $\omega^4$ like I'm looking for.
So in summary, does anybody know the formula that the software is using?